# number getting appended to &#8220 resulting in some weird special characters

Tags: java, jsp

The codes &#8220 and &#8221 are used to print “ ”, and  in between I can add strings or numbers like "test", "1235" etc, however strings getting enclosed with in “ ” properly, however when I try to enclose numbers , I am getting the special character� getting printed. 
Currently, in my java code, I am trying to print as below.

```
"&#8220"  + variable  + "&#8221"
```

here the variable can be string or number. May I know however we can make this work for numbers also please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numeric character entities must end with `;`. The codes you're looking for are `&#8220;` and `&#8221;`. Without the `;` they're invalid (though a browser may or may not tolerate the missing `;` in some situations). Details in [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#character-references).